# Angular HttpClient Get too large request problem

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

I deploy Angular web app, that consumes API from Spring Boot application. I use `HttpClient` to do `GET` request. When I try `GET` for a few records, everything is working fine, but when I try to get many records, in MB about 4/5MB, the browser crashes with an out-of-memory exception.

I think Angular can't parse JSON with a large number of records.

This is my code:

```
getDiarieLast30(): Observable<any[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(`http://${server}:${port}/api/diarie/cercaultimi90gg`)
}

public getDiarieLast30() {
    this.apiService.getDiarieLast30().subscribe(
      (data: any[]) => {
        this.listDiarie = data;
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      },
      error => {
        //Inserire codice Gestione Errore
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

Have you any idea ? or only way is pagination on server side?

Comment: While I'm not sure of your issue, but I have had successfully parsed 50-60 MB data at one point, which was taking around 10 mins to complete. So I don't think it's an inability of the browser/angular to parse large amount of data.

Comment: Check out many subscribers you registered, so if 1 request is firing a lot of subscribers to handle it, it may cause memory problems.

Comment: I do recommend to take the pagination approach.

Comment: Orel, sorry but im new in Angular, how I can check how subscribe register ? I send only 1 request, but I down't know how know if I handle many subscribe.

Comment: Hello, I discover that problem not on HttpClient but on directive ngFor, I try with code up, but also with "pipe async" to avoid memory leaks but no solve. Have you any suggestion ?